# Trouble with understanding transitive, symmetric and antisymmetric properties

Tags: relations

If $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $R$ an equivalence relation on $A$ if $R = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}$?

I'm having trouble understanding when a relation is symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive. Does the symmetric property require that ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ be present in $R$?

Answer (score 1):

The three properties required for an equivalence relation are 
1) reflexive: for any $x$ in the set $(x, x)$ is in the relation.  That is obviously true here- the set is $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and we have $(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)$ in the relation.

2) symmetric: if $(x, y)$ is in the relation then so is $(y,x)$.  Again that is obvious.  The only pairs in the relation are $(1, 1), (2, 2)$, and $(3, 3)$.   Reversing the order just gives the same thing again.

3) transitive: if $(x, y)$ **and** $(y, z)$ are in the relation, then so is $(x, z)$.  Once again, obvious! $(x, y)$ is in the relation only if $x= y$ but then we must have $y= z$ so $x= z$.  That is the same as $(z, z)$.

Actually, while there can be very complicated "equivalence relation", this particular one is the "epitome" of equivalence relations- it is the **identity** relation.  "$x$ is equivalent to $y$" if and only if "$x$ is **equal** to $y$".

(Anti-symmetric plays no role in equivalence relations but since you ask: where "symmetric" requires "if $(x, y)$ is in the relation, then $(y, x)$ is also".  "Anti-symmetric" requires "if $(x, y)$ is in the relation, then $(y, x)$ is **not**.)

Comment: Hi, you have been on the website long enough to know that we use MathJax.